# " 'case' is not a valid Java identifer"

Tags: java, spring, identificador

to com uma dúvida. To tentando criar um projeto springboot do zero, porém, quando eu tento mudar o nome do meu pacote, da esse problema. Quando eu coloco qualquer outro nome que não seja "case" no meio do pacote, da certo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexsander,

Sendo bem direto, `case` é uma palavra reservada e não pode ser usada no nome do pacote.

Veja a lista completa na documentação [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Espero ter ajudado